# How to generate AST for a module in erlang?

Tags: erlang, abstract-syntax-tree

how to generate an AST ,during runtime, for a whole module?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve that result.

For instance, you can use [`ktn_dodger`](https://github.com/inaka/katana-code/blob/7b2779882c8ba82db2f1e5147445616bf676a1dc/src/ktn_dodger.erl#L107) like we do on [the rebar3 formatter](https://github.com/AdRoll/rebar3_format/blob/3a0d5686328ca7422c20ca6593363ee67011b0dc/src/rebar3_ast_formatter.erl#L44-L48).

But, with just OTP…

```
1> epp_dodger:quick_parse_file("src/pt_example.erl").
{ok,[{attribute,1,module,pt_example},
     {attribute,3,export,[{a,0}]},
     {function,5,a,0,
               [{clause,5,[],[],
                        [{call,6,
                               {remote,6,{atom,6,io},{atom,6,format}},
                               [{string,6,"Hello!"}]}]}]}]}
```